# Apps script formatDate has wrong time

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

[image]

I'm working with apps script. In my code I have:

```
var date =Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
var now = Date.now();
```

I'm in the eastern time zone. I ran the function containing the lines above 1 minute ago. As you can see in the screenshot in the lower right corner the actual time and the time in the editor differ by an hour . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the scripts timezone?

Comment: Daylight savings? Try `EDT`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Cooper, you probably have a wrong time zone. Take a look in your project properties. Try checking the time zone in your spreadsheet too.

[image]

If that doesn't work, try also changing project time zone to a different one and changing it back to your correct time zone.

Comment: I tried changing the timezone on both spreadsheet and apps script project to something else and back to EST, it didn't help. They were originally est anyway.

Comment: That's weird. You're currently on daylight saving time In EST right now, right?

Comment: @JonatasGrandini solution is correct. Changing the Time zone in the project properties changes the time returned by Date(). I second his last question too.